# Activate Transit on Google Maps API v3 with user typed starting address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is the code I'm using right now to call Google Maps API:

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.88994,12.51383);

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 16,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
title: 'Studio medico'
});
}

function loadScript() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

You can see this live [here](http://danielamandolini.it/map.html). If you try to click on "(calcola percorso)", near "Mezzi pubblici" an input box appears. That's the starting address (saddress) parameter because the "Go" button will take you to Google Maps website and Transit service (and bring you through Transit to an "hardcoded" destination address starting from the address you typed).

Now, is it possible to start Transit directly in the map called with the script above (without going to Google Maps website)?
It would be awesome to have the users typing their address in the input form, clicking "Go" and then have the map above to be "turned" in Transit mode with a destination address I specify but the starting address selected by the users (from input form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You'll need to use the [`Directions` service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) in the Maps API. Here's an [example page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple).

OK, so far so good! I took a look at your latest code, and you're definitely on the right track (pun intended). As I mentioned in the comment, the problem is that you're calling the same `calcRoute()` function for both the select/option case and the text input form.

You could either break this into separate functions for each case, or perhaps use the same function but just pass in the element ID for each one. To do that, I'd give your text input field an ID:

```
<input type="text" id="startText" name="start" placeholder="Start address">
```

and then change your select element to pass its id:

```
<select id="start" onchange="calcRoute('start');">
```

and change the text input form too:

```
<form method="get" id="start" onsubmit="calcRoute('startText');" action="#" style="display:inline">
```

Now simply change the beginning of `calcRoute()`:

```
function calcRoute( input ) {
    var start = document.getElementById(input).value;
    ... remainder of existing code here ...
}
```

Or, as I mentioned in the comment, you could break these out into separate functions, perhaps `calcRouteFromSelect()` and `calcRouteFromText()`, and call each function from the respective form. These would each set up the input address as appropriate, and then call a common function to do the rest of the work. Either way would do the same job.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you help me a bit? I started to make some tests and this is what I have for now: http://ffio.it/test.html
As you can see the <option> method works. The problem is when I try to submit the starting address with the input form... what's wrong with my code? :) Thanks in advance!! :D

Comment: Hey, that's great progress! Nice work. The problem with the text input form is that you're calling the same `calcRoute()` function that you use for the select/option, but this function doesn't pick up the address from the text input field, it uses the select value. I can't do much code formatting in this comment, so I'll update the answer a bit...

Comment: Eheh, I try to do my best to achieve things. Also if I'm really a beginner with Javascript! And Google Maps API doc is really well written. :)

Comment: Oh! I don't need the <option> method. I only set it to let you see it worked. So the double-used function isn't a problem. Problem is: even if I removed the <option> method there's something wrong with the <input> :D
Take a look http://ffio.it/test2.html

EDIT: To make a test you can enter "Via Manin 72, Roma". It's an address near and should work. :)

Comment: This test has your code for <form> and <input> (and calcRoute function changed) but still doesn't seem to work.. :(  http://ffio.it/test3.html

Comment: It's submitting the form to your server, which is reloading your page. See how it gets a `?` at the end of the URL after you click Go? Try this to suppress the server submit: `onsubmit="calcRoute(); return false;"` Also the `onsubmit` should be on the `<form>` element, not the `<input>` element.

Comment: As you can see, it's still submitting to the server. Set a breakpoint in the `calcRoute` function and single step through the code. It is crashing somewhere inside the `directionsService.route()` call. That is why it's still submitting. I have to run to dinner and can't look at it any more right now, but that should give you a place to look and compare with your working code. Are you familiar with the JavaScript debuggers in browsers? The one in Chrome is excellent: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Ok! Good dinner! :D I'll have some investigation and will let you know.

Comment: Found out! This worked ;)

 <form>
  <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
  <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute();" value="Go">
 </form>

Comment: Take a look here, maybe you have a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259024/google-maps-api-map-width-gets-resized-onclick-but-route-is-still-loaded-with-o :D